# Excepción sin mensaje en .NET c# WindowsForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, xml, excepciones, .net-5

Estoy creando un programa llamado GestorConferencias, que, a través de una clase llamada DatosXML, lee y verifica -con un método llamado `ComprobacionInicial()`- los datos de un fichero XML que almacena la configuración básica del programa. Al abrir un formulario de ajustes, se instancia esta clase y se inicia en el constructor el método `ComprobacionInicial()`. El programa siempre me ha funcionado bien, sin embargo, hoy que acabo de iniciarlo, ya instalado, al pulsar en el botón que me abre el formulario de ajustes, se ha detenido.
Tengo una clase que en estos casos deja registro de los errores que han ocurrido en el programa, pero curiosamente ha registrado unos errores que no tienen Mensaje, sino solo información adicional, la StackTrace. Los dejo a continuación los registros de estos dos errores, justo antes de que el programa se detuviera:

```
MENSAJE:

INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:
   at GestorConferencias.DatosXML.ComprobacionInicial()
   at GestorConferencias.DatosXML..ctor()
   at GestorConferencias.Ajustes..ctor()
   at GestorConferencias.Principal.button1_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


MENSAJE:


INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:
   at GestorConferencias.DatosXML.ComprobacionInicial()
   at GestorConferencias.DatosXML..ctor()
   at GestorConferencias.Utilidades.UtilidadesExcepciones.UnhandledException(Exception e)
   at GestorConferencias.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_1(Object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(Exception e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr dwComponentID, msoloop uReason, Void* pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at GestorConferencias.Program.Main()
```

Este es el código de la clase DatosXML:

```
namespace GestorConferencias
{ 
    public class DatosXML
    {
        public const string CONFIG_FILE = "\\GestorConferencias\\config.xml";
        public XDocument configFile;
        // Aquí tendrían que estar todas las variables en las que se almacenará cada uno de los campos del XML

        public DatosXML()
        {
            ComprobacionInicial();
            try
            {
                CargarDatos();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                CrearXmlSiNoExisteOInvalido();
                CargarDatos();
            }
        }

        private void CargarDatos()
        {
            // Guarda cada dato en su variable correspondiente
        }

        private void ComprobacionInicial()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
                + CONFIG_FILE))
            {
                CrearXmlSiNoExisteOInvalido();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                    XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
// El archovo config.xsd contiene el esquema del fichero XML para verificar que sea correcto
                    XmlReader xsd = XmlReader.Create(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GestorConferencias.Files.config.xsd"));
                    schema.Add("", xsd);
                    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(
                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + CONFIG_FILE);
                    xdoc.Validate(schema, (sender, eventArgs) =>
                        {
                            CrearXmlSiNoExisteOInvalido();
                        }
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    CrearXmlSiNoExisteOInvalido();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void CrearXmlSiNoExisteOInvalido()
        {
            // Se elimina XML fallido
            File.Delete(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
                        + CONFIG_FILE);

            // Se crea el XML nuevo
        }
    }
}
```

La verdad es que no se porqué se ha podido producir el error, pues, aunque lo he intentado, no he conseguido repetirlo de nuevo, y al no tener la información del Mensaje de Error, no entiendo muy bien la información de `StackTrace`. ¿A qué podría deberse el error, y si es el caso cómo podría corregirlo?

Comment: Sugiero que hagas una depuración paso a paso para que puedas identificar la línea que produce el error. Además te recomiendo leer acerca de [try-catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) porque el uso que le estás dando no parece tener sentido.

Comment: No será por permisos de administrador?

Comment: Tu funcion crearXML no crea un xml, solo lo borra.. pero si no existe, va a tirar error...

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, perdona que no he especificado eso en el enunciado de la pregunta. El comentario que dice `//Se crea XML nuevo` lo he puesto para sustituir el código largo que tengo ahí para crear el XML en caso de que no exista. En realidad el método me funciona bien, siempre, aunque exista el XML, esté dañado, no exista... pero no entiendo a qué se debe que se hayan dado esos dos errores de repente, que de hecho han provocado que la aplicación se haya cerrado. Y luego no se han repetido...

Comment: Gracias @Carlos, no creo que sea por eso, pues siempre me ha funcionado. En realidad el método me funciona bien, siempre, pero no entiendo a qué se debe que se hayan dado esos dos errores de repente, que de hecho han hecho que la aplicación se haya cerrado. Y luego no se me han vuelto a repetir

Comment: Gracias @PabloGutiérrez, lo reviso, creo que tienes razón. Mirando un poco de nuevo hay cosas que no tienen mucho sentido que he hecho.  Aunque de todas formas, siempre me ha funcionado bien, pero ha sido de repente, que me ha dado ese fallo, que incluso no se vuelve a repetir... Así que quizás el fallo no sea por eso, pero aun y todo haré una depuración paso a paso, aunque me va ha costar reproducir el error, porque la verdad es que ha ocurrido sin más... Gracias!! 

Comment: Por eso te recomiendo mejorar el conocimiento con el manejo de excepciones (`try-catch`) aunque tu lógica considere reintentos. En el catch siempre deberías crear un registro (log) de la excepción que se produjo para que cuando ocurran (cómo te está pasando ahora) tengas dónde consultar las posibles causas. Ten en que las cosas siempre funcionan bien hasta que fallan y para eso tus programas también tienen que estar preparados.

Comment: Perfecto @PabloGutiérrez. Lo único en cuanto a eso, tengo otra clase con un método estático para gestionar los errores que, sea el error que sea que no esté depurado en el programa, se deriva a ese método estático y se guarda un registro del error. Pero lo que ocurre es que el error me devuelve esos datos que he publicado en el enunciado. El `mensaje` está vacío, y la `StackTrace` me devuelve eso que he puesto, pero no entiendo bien que puede significar. Vamos, en definitiva que el log ya lo he hecho, pero no entiendo bien los datos de ese log

Comment: No hay información suficiente para poder ayudarte.  Intenta reproducirlo y mejora la pregunta con nueva información que encuentres :)